# What is a good way to store processed CSV data to train model in Python?

Tags: python, keras, dataset, csv, serialisation

I have about 100MB of CSV data that is cleaned and used for training in Keras stored as Panda DataFrame. What is a good (simple) way of saving it for fast reads? I don't need to query or load part of it.

Some options appear to be:

- HDFS
- HDF5
- HDFS3
- PyArrow

Comment: When I want to got 5 mts in distance, I would rather walk than to take a car.

Comment: I think HDF5 is very good for you, your data size is small, I am working on h5 files it's fast.

Comment: Just leave it as CSV you don't need to do anything

Comment: Why not dump the dataframe `to_pickle` ? Easy, low memory, compression supported and fast loading without specifying columns or other parameters ...

Answer (score 5):

With 100MB data, you can store it in any filesystem as CSV since read is going to take less than a second.

Most of the time is going to be spent by dataframe runtime in parsing data and creation of in-memory data structures.

Comment: +1 Always profile first. Unless OP has evidence that reading from the data is causing the major bottleneck - they shouldn't be investing resources in optimising it.

Comment: That's a good point. I should find out how long it takes. Also, I can see that converting from CSV to DataFrame could take time as well...

Answer (score 3):

You can find a nice benchmark for every approach in [here](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2015/03/16/Fast-Serialization).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your data size is not that much huge, but there are some debates whenever you deal with big data [What is the best way to store data in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23028862/5120235) and [Optimized I/O operations in Python](https://towardsdatascience.com/optimized-i-o-operations-in-python-194f856210e0). They all depend on the way the serialisation occurs and the policies which are taken in different layers. For instance, security, valid transactions and such things. I guess the latter link can help you dealing with large data.